# d3 floating grouped bar with ranged values in a timeline

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

im trying to understand what tools i need to use as im new to d3 and didnt find any thing related...

i need a area chart that is like bars but can float and be on multiple values both on the x and y axis.

in this example the values are days but it might be hours/months etc...

need to know the direction i need to go.. / the right term to search...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no significant difference between drawing this chart and a normal bar chart.

- And you need to define some [scales](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale) that will map the values in your data to co-ordinates on your chart.
- You need to draw some `rect` [shapes](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape).

So, in the above example you would define a [time scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#time-scales) that, given an input date, will map that to a certain x co-ordinate on your chart. You can then use that to determine both the `x` co-ordinate for where the left-hand-side of a rectangle will be, and to work out how wide the rectangle needs to be.

```
const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([d3.min(dateValuesInMyDataset, d => d.date), d3.max(dateValuesInMyDataset, d => d.date)])
  .range([0, widthOfMyChart]);
```

The above `xScale` if given the earliest date in your dataset would return the value `0`, because this is the x co-ordinate representing that date.

Similarly, you would want to construct a [linear scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#linear-scales) which defines how to map the numerical range of values in your dataset, to the y co-ordinates in your chart. Then you can use the scale to determine the y value and height of all of the rectangles in your chart.

There are lots of good examples of this on [ObservableHQ.com](https://observablehq.com/) that you can browse and see the code for.